# What is the most common pronunciation of "yahoo"?

Tags: prononciation, informatique

I pronounce X.Y@yahoo.com as: " X/pwɛ̃/Y arobase /ˈjɑːhuː/ com ". I noticed that many times I am not understood. What is the most common pronunciation of yahoo in French?

Comment: Je ne le prononce pas comme indiqué sur [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!) en français mais je le prononce comme [indiqué pour l'anglais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!).  Ainsi que les gens autour de moi, mais tout le monde parle anglais autour de moi....

Comment: @None Parfois quand c'est employé non pas pour le domaine de messagerie mais de manière expressive par exemple etc. la différence c'est pas tant ə ou ɑ mais bien l'un ou l'autre court avec l'enchaînement (ˈ) immédiat plutôt que (ː) la pause comme pour le nom. Je sais pas pourquoi l'article fr. sur Wiki a voulu utiliser cet API-là avec enchaînement, il leur fallait mettre (:) il me semble...  je veux dire qu'ils mettent ə ou ɑ... ou je suis dans le champ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everyone I know pronounce it /ja.u/, like *[yaourt](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/yaourt)* without its last consonants. Separated but short vowels, no /h/.

Answer (score 1):

Il semblerait que le h ne soit jamais  prononcé en français. Cependant, personnellement je vois pas comment seulement l'ajout d'un h puisse rendre la prononciation incompréhensible.

[Forvo 1](https://fr.forvo.com/word/yahoo/#fr) 4 prononciations dont une belge, la première ; 'ja.u\

[Forvo 2](https://fr.forvo.com/word/@yahoo.fr/) 1 prononciation ; même chose que précédemment

[HowToPronounce](https://fr.howtopronounce.com/) Cette prononciation dévie des précédentes, mais seulement en cela que le \u\ devient \w\ ; le h n'est cependant toujours pas prononcé.  'jaw\

Voici une liste de 16 prononciations de « Yahoo » en contexte : [HowToPronounce 2](https://fr.howtopronounce.com/search/french/yahoo) ; il n'y a pas variation.